Android app that transcribes phone calls and allows you to tap to see unknown or unfamiliar word definitions
I am looking for an Android application that while holding a conversation with someone you can view a text transcript of the conversation
and
when you hear a word, that, you do not know, or are not familiar with, you can click or tap the screen, and, the app fetches and displays a definition of the word within solid lives in a different color, embedding it in the text transcript.
If the definition contains further unknown or unrecognized words, you can also tap on them to view them embedded in the text transcript.
Thank you for your support.
Kind regards
Best regards
